# Example for Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've studied recently about Eigenspaces and I was wondering:
giving the following properties:
$$V=\mathbb{R}^3, T:V\rightarrow V, v\in V,T(v)=\lambda\cdot V\Rightarrow v\in V_\lambda\subset V$$
Is there an example for $T$ such that $dim V_\lambda=2 $?

EDIT:
I gave some wrong arguments, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course:

$$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\lambda=1\;,\;\;V_1=\left\{\,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^3\,\right\}\subset\Bbb R^3\;,\;\;\dim V_1=2$$

Comment: I wasn't probably clear enough, i meant that the eigenspace isn't the entire space. (i wrote it in the end of the math line that the eigenspace is a subset but not equal, i'll edit it)

Comment: Then of course there is **not** such an example, as you wrote $\;V=\Bbb R^2\;$ , which is of dimension two! That's absurd...And in higher mathematics, $\;A\subset B\;$ is usually taken as "A is a subset of B" and that's all, which means either a proper subset or the whole set. This, though, may depend on the author's definitions.

Comment: I'm really sorry, fixed the question,

Comment: I don't understand the example. isn't T(1,1,1)=(1,1,0)? how can lambda=1 be an eigenvalue? Am I missing a basic understanding of eigenvalue?

Comment: @YaronScherf $(1,1,1)$ is not an eigenvector, but $(1,1,0)$ is.

Comment: Ok now I see it, thanx

Answer (score 3):

The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
4&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1
}
$$
has the two-dimensional eigenspace $V_1 = \{(0,y,z):y,z \in \Bbb R\}$.  The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&1}
$$
is similar to the matrix above, and has the two dimensional eigenspace $V_1 = \{(x,y,z) : x + y + z = 0\}$.